# Visual Workflow Display Text Not showing

Tags: account, visual-workflow

I have a visual workflow with an input screen for users to enter in certain data. On this input screen I want to show a fields from the Account object as display text. The field exists on the Account object as a custom formula read-only text field. It is not actually showing as display text, however. The value of this field will show up on the input screen if I set it as an input text field, but won't show up as an output display text. What could be the reason for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields will not display in a flow text area, the workround is to create another text field then use a normal Workflow rule to populate the text field and use that in your Visual Flow text area.

It is a bit long winded but it will work.